# Keycloak Provider login results in request-compose timeout error

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, nginx-reverse-proxy, strapi

**Setup**:

- We have a HTTPS **strapi** application and **keycloak** is configured as an **identity provider** with the corresponding client id and secret from the keycloak client. Both strapi and keycloak are behind **nginx**.
- We have a keycloak server, where the strapi is added as a client with the necessary redirect URIs configured.
- Also, the provider.js and bootstrap.js is setup as suggested in the reference:

  - [Strapi Documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/users-permissions.html#adding-a-new-provider-to-your-project),

**Issue:**

- Strapi throws an error when trying to access the client:

{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":{"message":"No access_token."},"data":{"message":"No access_token."}}

https://our.website.domain/strapi/auth/keycloak/callback?error=request-compose%3A%20timeout

- In the logs, we see that the access token is not received and hence the error is thrown from strapi end. [example provider.js line](https://github.com/marcelmaatkamp/strapi-extension-keycloak/blob/bb7f1de2a1e7dbd029cfef51caf7b027e3c07ff6/strapi/extensions/users-permissions/services/Providers.js#L30)

**Verification**:

- Strapi is able to use other social identity providers like GitHub to authenticate as expected.
- We are able to use Postman to get the access token from keycloak by posting to https://our.website.domain/auth/realms/exampleRealmName/protocol/openid-connect/token as suggested in this [comment (step1)](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3072#issuecomment-691411183).
- We are able to use the access token to get response from Strapi through Postman.  https://our.website.domain/connect/IDP-Name/callback as suggested [here (step 2)](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3072#issuecomment-691411183)

Any inputs or advise on what could be the issue?

Thank you in advance.